# Taking data from database

Tags: php, database, database-schema

I have data saved in database from forms like this how:

```
    a:3:{i:0;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:36;s:10:"user_value";s:5:"John";}i:1;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:37;s:10:"user_value";s:21:"john@gmail.com";}i:2;a:2:{s:8:"field_id";i:38;s:10:"user_value";s:159:"some form text";}}
```

Where I can get more information how to deal with this saving style? I need to take emails, and other inputs to array in php.

Comment: This is a serialized array. [unserialize it](http://us1.php.net/unserialize)

Comment: $data = unserialize($data); //considering $data has you db extrtacted data (i know  Ohgodwhy said it already but the user may not understand what you mean by that, since he didn't understand the format at first glance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

This serialize styled data stored in database. You need to do reverse it.
You can take help from: https://www.php.net/unserialize

- Thanks